# Code won't go into the except clause for error handling

Tags: try-except, custom-error-handling

I am new to python and am trying to make some code work. In the code I force an error and hope to activate the error handler.

I have tried to google this problem, but not been able to find a solution...

```py
#Main code
from Calculations import Errormessages as em
x = 'a'
try:
    y = 2/x
    print("y is:", y)

except em.error_str_input:
    print("This works (1)")

except error_0_input:
    print("This works (2)")

#From the Errormessages-file I import the following code:
class error(Exception):
    print("Wrong instruction given, please try again ...")
    pass
class error_str_input(error):
    print("... input numbers (not strings)!")
    pass
class error_0_input(error):
    print("... cannot divide by zero!")
    pass
```

I had expected:

```
Wrong instruction given, please try again ...
... input numbers (not strings)!
This works (1)
```

But resulted in the following error message:

```
File "//.../file.py", line 10, in <module>
    y = 2/x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to try-except.

you are trying to divide int/str this is not possible.

I think you have to change the x value or use `ord(x)` while dividing.

e.g => `y = 2/ord(x)`